# BEM & Sass - how to approach a basic, global "style guide"-type rules?

Tags: sass, bem

I'm using BEM for everything and appreciating the advantages.

There is a basic global style guide provided by the designers, including

- Header1
- Header2
- body text
- primary button
- secondary button

(and a few other things).

My instinct is to create SASS rules for these, and then pull them into BEM blocks as necessary.

For example, header1 would be:

```
@mixin header1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  font-color: '#e3e3e3';
}
```

then my BEM block could be:

```
pane {
  &__title {
    @include header1;
  }
}

form {
  &__overview {
     @include header1;
  }
}
```

The alternatives are:

1. Repeat the rules for header1 inline 
   (*duplicative. conforms to BEM's everything is a flat module*)
2. create a BEM block named "header1" and do a BEM mix in the markup
   (*would always go with the same BEM elements, so seems like not the correct path*)

What is your approach to this? Is this approach contrary to the spirit of BEM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a placeholder for header1

```
%header1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Gotham';
  font-color: '#e3e3e3';
}
```

and extend classes to this 'abstract' selector

```
pane {
  &__title {
    @extend header1;
  }
}

form {
  &__overview {
    @extend header1;
  }
}
```

Comment: ok so at least I'm not the only one that thinks just repeating things to stick to the spirit of BEM is not always ideal.   @ extend makes it a little harder to read the output CSS which is why I was thinking to use @ incude instead - it puts the rules inline.

Comment: which file do you put header1 at?

Comment: In my structure i have a file named _typography.scss where i put all rule about headers, p...

Answer (score 2):

You may create generic `heading` block with different modifiers for each level: `heading_level_1`, `heading_level_2`, etc. And then [mix](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix) such blocks with needed element: `<h1 class="pane__title heading heading_level_1"></h1>`.

So now it'll be possible to separate generic things like font-size from specific things like positioning (margins, etc) of `pane__title`.

For more examples of such approach see: https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#mixes.